# Configuring SSRS 2019 Database Fails

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2016, windows-server-2016, ssrs-2019

We are trying to install SSRS 2019 on Windows Server 2016. For the SSRS Database the SQL Server 2016 is on another Windows Server 2016. Both the server are on the same domain and are both pingable to each other.

While configuring the database, get the below error. Have checked articles which point to :

1. RPC service should be running on the database and the reporting sever... This is running.
2. DCOM service should be running on database and the reporting sever... This is running.
3. Giving Administrator rights to the service account in which the SSRS service... This is given.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Thanks

Neeraj

```
Microsoft.ReportingServices.WmiProvider.WMIProviderException: An error occurred when attempting to connect to the report server remote procedure call (RPC) end point. Verify that the Report Server Windows service is running, and then retry the operation.

 ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The RPC server is not listening. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706B3)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WmiProvider.RSWmiAdmin.ThrowOnError(ManagementBaseObject mo)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WmiProvider.RSWmiAdmin.GenerateDatabaseScript(String databaseName, Int32 lcid, Boolean isSharePointIntegrated, String& script)
   at ReportServicesConfigUI.WMIProvider.RSReportServerAdmin.GenerateDatabaseScript(String databaseName, Int32 lcid, Boolean isSharePointIntegrated, String& script)
```

Comment: I *assume* that the SSRS Service account is running under a domain account? Also, though I can't find any specific documentation to back it up it not being supported, why are you running SSRS 2019 against a SQL Server 2016 host?

Comment: It was running under the NTService Account, which I changed it after reading your suggestion, but still the error persist.

SSRS 2019 with SQL 2016 is used becuase of licensing reasons.

One can use SSRS 2019 and different flavours of SQL Server
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/ssrs-report-server-create-a-report-server-database?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Also have gone an enabled the Ports on the Windows Server 2016 (SQL Server).
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-windows-firewall-for-database-engine-access?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

Since the SSRS 2019 POrtal is on one server and the SSRS 2019 Database is on another server, the only way to create the SSRS database, was to install the SSRS 2019 on the database server and create the database.

This Works fine!

But in PowerBI Server, this problem doesn't exsits